# Displaying ✓ mark on valid input fields using pseudo-elements

Tags: html, css, validation, input, pseudo-element

Below is an attempt I have created to use the CSS `content` property to add the tick mark to show on valid required fields however it has not been successful.

As I haven’t really seen it done this way, is it just not possible to do it like this? Would it be more efficient to just use JavaScript?

I would like to hear about peoples’ opinions on the way I should implement this feature for user feedback.

```css
input[type=text]:valid {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
input[type=text]:valid:after {
  content: '✓';
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<p>Username:</p>
<input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" pattern="^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]{1,20}$" title="Must Include Characters And Numbers only" required>
```

This essentially answered my question:
http://codepen.io/brentrobbins/pen/beexQR

Comment: See demo [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38681057/747579) then tell me

Comment: @Xufox : IT IS Not duplicated.. because he want to apply :after for **VALID** input , not any INPUT.

Comment: there are options like this without using javascript http://codepen.io/brentrobbins/pen/beexQR which is more preferable

Comment: @MarkoMackic this was the answer I was looking for. Thank you

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI What is the big difference there? The answers from the other question state that pseudo-elements are impossible for _any_ input, so why would it be an _entirely_ different question to apply it for a particular class of inputs? Even the one answer here restates that and provides some alternatives _and_ any answer from that other question is sufficient to answer _this_ question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`input` can't have `::before` or `::after` elements. Try wrapping a `<span>` around the input and do the `span:after`

Or just use an `img` element after, as this will work too.

---

## DEMO :

I used also **[jQuery#valid](https://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/)** to change CSS class of that `span`.

```js
$('[name=username]').keyup(function(){

    if($('form').valid()){
         $(this).parent().removeClass().addClass('isvalid');
     }else{
             $(this).parent().removeClass().addClass('notvalid');
        
     }

})
```

```css
span.isvalid:after
{
  content: '✓';
  color: green;
  }
 span.notvalid:after{
     content: '×';
     color: red;
   
 } 

.isvalid input[name=username]{
 border: 2px solid green;
}
.notvalid input[name=username]{
 border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

<p>Username:</p>
<form>
<span class="notvalid"><input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" pattern="^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]{1,20}$" title="Must Include Characters And Numbers only" required></span>
  </form>
```